# Summernot is not working in MVC4 but working in MVC 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, summernote

I want to use summernot in ASP.NET MVC4 application and below is the code which I am using

```
   @section featured {
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link  href="~/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/summernote.js" ></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.summernote').summernote();
        });
    </script>


    <div class="summernote">summernote</div>

}
```

I have used ASP.NET MVC-4 internet application. It is not displaying summernote.

Amazingly, same code is working is ASP.NET MVC 2

is it because ASP.NET MVC 4 include addition bundle which is restricting summernote publish?
Below is the console log

[image]

**Important Note**

**When I used the same code in ASP.NET MVC4 application "Basic project" it is working fine.**

Now, I am sure it is because of additional scripts being added by ASP.NET MVC4 "Internet Project".. Any clue why it is happening?

Comment: _summernote.js_  is in root direcotry of project?

Comment: Yes.. it is same in both project (i.e. at root)

Comment: is is not in scripts or js folder , it is in root folder?

Comment: Yes.. its on the root folder. I did the same with <link href="~/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
    <script src="~/summernote.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out; it was because of the jquery bundle which was present in the _layout page. Somehow, it was restricting summernote.js

When I removed script rendering line from the layout, everything went fine.

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

I believe it can either be done by replacing jquery libraries from script folder with the latest one or to remove all jquery and load it from online reference.